# Why does Xcode ask for "codesign wants to access key access in your keychain" before it will compile my app

Tags: xcode, macos

I am trying to learn Swift and storyboards on macOS and am putting together a very simple document based app. When I tried to compile it wouldn't compile without allowing a access in the keychain.

This worked before a couple days ago when I was copying in a tutorial app.

I must have messed something up in the app setup, but I sure can't see what.

Xcode 9.2, macOS 10.13.3

Answer (score 2):

By comparing with previous test app that didn't have this problem, I found that the need to codesign was because in 'build settings' the code signing identity had been set to "Developer". Changing this to 'other' and typing "-" fixed the problem. 
Since this app is going nowhere off of my development computer, the code doesn't need to be signed. Now I can compile and test.